# Android Network Service Discovery get hostname (mDNS/Zeroconf)

Tags: android, mdns, zeroconf, nsd

I am trying to get the hostname from a service that is advertising itself on my local network using mDNS/Zeroconf. I am using Android's Network Service Discovery API, but it seems as if Android doesn't use the advertised hostname but tries to do a reverse DNS lookup and if that fails only returns the IP address.

On my Macbook I do can do the following:

`$ dns-sd -B _myservice._tcp
DATE: ---Mon 29 Oct 2018---
17:35:25.332  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R    Flags  if Domain               Service Type         Instance Name
17:35:25.333  Add        2  10 local.               _myservice._tcp.     My Service Name`

`$ dns-sd -L "My Service Name" _myservice._tcp
DATE: ---Mon 29 Oct 2018---
17:38:35.423  ...STARTING...
17:38:35.423  My\032Service\032Name._myservice._tcp.local. can be reached at test.my.service.local.:443 (interface 10)`

I can then use the returned hostname (`test.my.service.local`) to find the corresponding IP. I've got this working correctly on iOS using `NSNetServiceBrowser`.

On Android in my `onServiceDiscovered` if I do the following:
`private static Map<String, Object> OnServiceDiscovered(NsdServiceInfo info) {
  Log.d(TAG, info.getHost().getHostAddress());
  Log.d(TAG, info.getHost().getHostName());
}`

I do get the correct IP address, but getHostName returns "raspberrypi.local" (from /etc/hostname) or on another network only the IP address. My suspicion is that on Android getHost().getHostName() is doing a reverse DNS lookup and ignores the hostname being advertised with mDNS altogether.

Is there any way to get the hostname from mDNS on Android?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?